# Qual a origem do termo "balamento" que se usa na altura da Páscoa?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, origem-histórica, regionalismo

Qual a origem do termo "balamento" que é usado na altura da Páscoa?

#### Contexto

Balamento são pontos numa competição de Páscoa.

Até o domingo de Páscoa são criadas equipas de duas pessoas onde quem surpreender o outro com termo balamento uma vez por dia ganha: por exemplo, 15 dias antes da Páscoa = 15 balamentos. Quem tiver mais balamentos ganha. 1 balamento é ganho quando 1 dos jogadores disser a palavra balamento primeiro durante esse dia. Existem outras variações  (e.g., 3 balamentos num dia). Na vitória (+ balamentos) é acordado um prêmio, por exemplo, um saco de amêndoas.

Comment: Pesquisando no Google diz até que a origem é brasileira, mas não recordo de nada deste genero.

Comment: Não conheço nenhum termo relacionado à Páscoa chamado "balamento". É possível que haja algum uso regional ou local desse termo, mas não é algo amplamente difundido ou reconhecido em nível nacional ou internacional. Se você puder fornecer mais informações sobre o contexto ou a região em que esse termo é usado, posso tentar investigar melhor sua origem e significado.

Comment: Ate ao domingo de Páscoa sao criadas equipas de duas pessoas onde quem surpreender o outro com termo balamento uma vez por.dia ganha ex 15 dias antes da bascoa = 15 balamentos . Quem tiver mias blamantos ganha. 1 balamento é  ganho quando 1 dos jogadores disser a palavra balamneto primeiro durante esse dia. Existem outras variacoes  (3 balamentos num dia) . NA vitoria + balamentos é acordado um premio, ex um saco de amêndoas

Comment: @ClMend Adicionei a informação de teu comentário à pergunta.

Comment: O [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/balamento) sugere que a origem pode ser a palavra "bala".

Comment: Está quase a chegar a altura do balamento, logo depois do Carnaval, até À Pascoa!!